# How to write a generic function with a type parameter that satisfies its own Self bound?

Tags: generics, rust

I'm trying to write a function that receives a mutable reference to a generic struct from someone else's crate (so I can't modify that struct's definition). Some of the methods implemented for the struct are only available when the struct satisfies a certain bound:

```
impl<'s, 'p: 's, P> TryCatch<'s, P>
where
  Self: AsMut<HandleScope<'p, ()>>,
{
    // functions that I want to use
}
```

My function works fine if I declare it like this:

```
fn my_func(try_catch: &mut v8::TryCatch<v8::HandleScope>)
```

or like this:

```
fn my_func(try_catch: &mut v8::TryCatch<v8::EscapableHandleScope>)
```

Since there's no function overloading in Rust, I have to either write two functions, write my own trait and then implement it for both flavors of `TryCatch`, or come up with some clever way to make the compiler accept either flavor as an argument.

I can pick either of the first two options and it's not a big deal, but I'm trying to learn Rust better, and I was wondering if anyone could help me get the third option working.

PS: Sorry for the clumsy title. If there's a better way to phrase it, let me know.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't contain a [mre]. Can you elaborate a little, preferably with either a minimized dummy library or the actual library you're relying on? I'm guessing the answer is something like `fn my_func<'s, 'p: 's, P>(try_catch: &mut v8::TryCatch<'s, P>) where v8::TryCatch<'s, P>: AsMut<HandleScope<'p, ()>>` (basically: take the bounds and generics from the function you want to use and copy them on the function where you use it) but it's difficult to be sure because I can't see your error.

Comment: @trentcl That's exactly what I needed! Sorry for the lack of reproducible example, but I was convinced there was something simple that I just didn't grok about Rust. None of the languages I've used before allow me to specify a complex type definition like that on the "left side" of the constraint. Do you think it would be enough to convert your comment to answer so I can accept it, or should I rework the question to make it more reproducible?

Comment: It's really up to you. If you'd like this Q&A to be preserved for future askers, I'd suggest taking a stab at making a MRE and I'll add an answer when I get some time. But if you don't have time or aren't sure how, that's fine. (But the question will probably be closed without an MRE, whether or not I write a proper answer, so I'm not inclined to at the moment) Either way, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want also making your function generic. I don't know your particular case, but for instance, both `v8::HandleScope` and `v8::EscapableHandleScope` implement the `v8::Scoped` trait.

So if that's all you need to know about that type you can rewrite your function like:

```
fn my_func<S>(try_catch: &mut v8::TryCatch<S>)
where
    S: v8::Scoped
```

or more shortly:

```
fn my_func<S: v8::Scoped>(try_catch: &mut v8::TryCatch<S>)
```